# How to click a button in row in a table using protractor js

Tags: testing, jasmine, protractor

I am writing protractor test cases. I want to click on edit button. When I am checking by `id` it is not found.

Code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Code</th>
          <th>Start Date</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="batch in batches.list">
         <td><a ui-sref="root.courses.detail.batches.assessments({ batch_id: batch.id,assessment_status: 'published'})">BID00{{batch.id}}</a></td>
         <td>{{batch.start_date}}</td>
         <td> 
             <button id="edit" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Edit" ng-controller="batchesCtrl" ng-click="edit_batch(batch.id)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button> 
             <button type="button" id="delete(batch.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Delete" ng-click="remove_batch(1, batch.id)" confirmation-needed="Do you really want to delete this batch?"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></i></button>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: When i use element(by.repeater('batch in batches.list').row(0)).element(by.id('edit')).click(); i got Error: No element found using locator: by.repeater(batch in batches.list").row("0")"

Comment: Could you please suggest? @Andres D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am not sending delay so what happen i am checking for the button which is not loaded
ptor.sleep(500); fixes my problem. It took so much time to identify

Answer (score 5):

There are a few problems in your example. In html an ID should be unique on a page. So you can't use an id inside an element that repeats.

You have several options. You could address the button by one of it's styleclasses that the other button does no have like

```
element(by.repeater('batch in batches.list').row(0)).element(by.css('button.btn-default')).click();
```

You can also just specify you want the first button it finds like

```
element(by.repeater('batch in batches.list').row(0)).element(by.css('button:first-of-type')).click();
```

Alternatively you can also address the element with only css. Sometimes that is easier to maintain than the repeater:

```
element(by.css('tr:first-of-type > td:last-child > button:first-of-type')).click();
```

Comment: When i use last option i got No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("tr:first-of-type > td:last-child > button:first-of-type")

Comment: When i use second option i got  Error: No element found using locator: by.repeater(batch in batches.list").row("0")"

Comment: That's wierd. I tested it. What protractor version do you use and when you start protractor in debug and use browser.debugger(); before the click expression, can you see the button?